# Is it possible to only get non alphabetic, English alphabet, and non numeric from a column DB2

Tags: regex, db2, db2-400

Sometimes I get Ÿ (hex C5B8: 2 bytes, 1 character) in my database and I have a script that processes multiple data which can't read that data since it doesn't know what to do with it so it stops the whole process and I have to go into my logs and see where the error is so that I can restart the whole process.

I want to execute a query that only gives me characters that are not in the english alphabet so that I can see if they should be changed.

I tried to only look for UTF8 characters but Ÿ is a UTF8 char so I need to go for another aproach.

words containing other than:

> A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z

and numbers

> 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9

excluding alpanumeric (in case someone writes a address like this)

> h3ll0

I was thinkg something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myCol != (/^[A-Za-z]+$/)
```

something like that where I only get columns that have characters which do not belong to the english alphabet or numbers 0-9

Comment: Try `WHERE myCol NOT REGEXP '^[a-z0-9]*$'` or `WHERE myCol NOT REGEXP BINARY '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$'`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew **Token REGEXP was not valid. Valid tokens: LIKE BETWEEN.**

Comment: @learningbyexample, your question is tagged 'mysql' so we assume you're using MySQL, and REGEXP is a valid predicate in MySQL. If you're using a different SQL database, please edit the tags of your question appropriately. Different SQL databases have different syntax for using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. Basically you want to find all columns that have words with characters that are not in the English alphabet? If so this might work:

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `myCol` NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]'
```

EDIT: This answer was written for the old tag to this question which was "mySQL", you've change it to db2. I've tried modifying it for db2 11 but It's at best an educated guess:

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `myCol` NOT REGEXP_LIKE '[A-Za-z0-9]'
```

Comment: **Token ` was not valid. Valid tokens: ( + - ? : DAY INF NAN NOT RID ROW RRN CASE CAST CHAR DATE DAYS.**

Comment: sorry just look at my database and it's DB2

Comment: @learningbyexample please check with double quotation marks instead of single quotation marks. Also, it might not like qutation marks around table and column names

Comment: just tried it **Keyword REGEXP_LIKE not expected. Valid tokens: LIKE BETWEEN.** gives this error

Comment: SELECT myCol FROM myTable WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE (myCol, '[A-Za-z0-9]')
I tired this but I get this error **QQQSVREG in QSYS type *SRVPGM not found.**

Comment: Check you OS version, you need to be at least in V7R2 with TR2 PTF applied. Or V7R1 with TR9.  And for these RegExp functions, you also need option 39 - International Components for Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the

> TRANSLATE

function - see [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscatrans.htm)

Translate all regular characters and number to an empty string - like:

```
select translate(mycol, '', 'ABCDEFGabcdefghi1234567890')
  from mytable
```

This is no the complete solution but you should get the idea. This works in DB2 LUW and is available für i series.

Comment: **Argument 02 of function TRANSLATE not valid.**

Comment: so check the documentation - in LUW argument 3 and 2 are vice versa but I took this from thedocumentation - I have no i series to test it....